Is the normal cone of a subspace its complement?
Let $L$ be a subspace, the normal cone of $L$ at $x \in L$ is defined by
$$
N_{L}(x)=\{y|\left<y,z-x\right>\leq 0, \ \forall z \in L\}.
$$
I am trying to prove $N_{L}(x)=L^{\bot}$. I can prove $L^{\bot} \subseteq N_{L}(x)$, but I cannot prove the reverse direction, $N_{L}(x)\subseteq L^{\bot}$, and I am not sure the conclusion is right.

Take $y\in N_L(x)$, $d\in L$. Then $x\pm d \in L$, so that
$$
\langle y, \ (x\pm d)-x \rangle \le 0,
$$
which implies $\langle y,d\rangle=0$ for all $d\in L$.
